# Finishing SQA reviews, counts sticks after I empty my que

Tags: support

How do I get my review count to zero? Currently its always above 8 even if I empty my que. Like in this screenshot its still 10.

[image]

I tried looking at the *Tools* link left of *Review*, but I can't seem to find anything that will lower the count.

What do I need todo? Please enlighten me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the number of possible reviews for SQA, not just my own. Guess I have to motivate others to empty their review queues :)

This is explain more in detail in this question: [Notification for reviews shows way too many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230742/notification-for-reviews-shows-way-too-much)